# How to stop swiper slider autoplay immediately on hover with speed attribute without take a long time when stop autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

When I use speed attribute with swiper slider It's take more time to stop swiper autoplay on hover

```
var SwiperTop = new Swiper('.swiper--top', {
    spaceBetween: 0,
    speed: 10000,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 0.1,
    },
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView:'auto',
    allowTouchMove: false,
    disableOnInteraction: true,
    autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
});
$(".swiper--top").hover(function() {
    SwiperTop.autoplay.stop();
}, function() {
    SwiperTop.autoplay.start();
});
```

I have a problem with swiper slider when I use speed attribute the swiper doesn't stop immediately and take more time to stop autoplay on mouse hover

Comment: Your "_swiper_" is [this](https://swiperjs.com/)?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? I mean HTML, CSS if usedm and javascript/jquery